# D3js axis clipping not working with g element

Tags: d3.js, svg, clip-path

This adds a circle, assigns the clip path:

```
    focus.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data).enter().append("circle")
  .attr("clip-path", "url('#clip')")
  .attr("class","dot")

  .attr("r", 4.5)
  .attr("opacity", 0.7)
  .style("fill",  "steelblue");
```

This adds/clones an xml node, which is an svg image "B" , and assigns the clip path:

```
    var xmlSvgB = d3.select(xmlSvg).select('#b').node();
var gXml = focus.selectAll(".icon")
.data(data ).enter().append(function(){return xmlSvgB.cloneNode(true);})
.attr("clip-path", 'url("#clip2")')
.attr('class', 'icon')
.attr("opacity", 0.7)
.attr('id',function(d){return 'b_' + d.date.getTime();})
.attr('transform', function(d){
var xdate = x(d.date) - 11;
return "translate(" + xdate   + "," +  15 + ") scale(0.8)" ;});
```

I cannot figure out why clipping works just fine on a circle, but not on the group element... it seems like it should.

[An example of the problem d3 axis clipping works for circle, but not working for svg group element](https://bl.ocks.org/powersparks/a4ffbd43a4f59f932d99e40d2b500095)

The two clip-paths are setup like:

```
      var defs =  focus.append("defs");
    defs.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")

      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y",0)
      .attr("width", width )
      .attr("height", height);

      defs.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip2")

        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y",0)
        .attr("width", width )
        .attr("height", height)
        ;
```

Note: if console is running, sometimes a "cloneNode(true)" fails. This is just cloning the "g" element.

Comment: the clipPath element doesn't support "structural elements" which is interesting, but should not effect my implementation... see:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath

Answer (score 0):

Wow. okay, I hope this helps someone else. I spent a few days thinking about this.. and really, a few of the discussions on Stackoverflow clued me in...
the trick is to append a "g" element and assign the "clip-path" to this top element like:

```
    var xmlSvgB = d3.select(xmlSvg).select('#b').node();
    var gXml = focus.selectAll(".icon-g")
    .data(data ).enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("clip-path", function(){ return 'url("#clip")';})
    .attr("class","icon-g")
    .append(function(){return xmlSvgB.cloneNode(true);})
    .attr("opacity", 0.7)
   .attr('id',function(d){return 'i_' + d.date.getTime();})
   .attr('transform', function(d){
   var xdate = x(d.date) - 11;
   return "translate(" + xdate   + "," +  15 + ") scale(0.8)" ;});
```

this will then clip the polygon..

[here is the same code, shown in the original problem, and now zooming and panning correctly clip the svg element](https://bl.ocks.org/powersparks/146f356ecf8df48616542e45a1c8d132)